# UITableview section issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview with two sections. I have loaded values from same array to the tableview. It is working fine, and I have customized the alpha value of the cell text in section 1, 1.0 and in section 2, 0.5. When I scroll down the table it is working fine. But when I scroll up (bottom to top), the alpha value of the section got changed to 0.5 (that is the value of section 1). Then the alpha value in both the sections are 0.5. Why it is happening so? Does anybody know the solution, please let me know.

Comment: This will be a problem in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Please update your question with the code from that method.

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake. I set the alpha value for each section separately. Now its working fine. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are reusing the cells, but not resetting the alpha values in the cell you are reusing.

If you have a line with

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, then this is retrieving a cell for reuse - if you use this reused cell then you need to make sure you reset the alpha values of the background accordingly because it could be reused for a different row to the one the cell was originally created for.

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake. I set the alpha value for each section separately. Now its working fine. Anyway thanks.